# How does an anonymous class access parent class' parameters?

Tags: java, parameter-passing, anonymous-class

Given this SSCE:

```
public class AnonymousClassTest {

    String param = "initial";

    void test() {
        Runnable runnalbe = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(param);
            }
        };
        runnalbe.run();

        param = "after";

        runnalbe.run();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new AnonymousClassTest().test();
    }

}
```

Could anyone point to a part in JLS or any other documentation which explains why the result is

```
initial
after
```

Instead of not compiling due to lack of `final` for `param`, or just printing:

```
initial
initial
```

I remember requiring `final` when passing parameter this way to an anonymous class, but it seems not to be the case in Java 7. What has changed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing has changed. Fields of the outer class are always accessible to inner classes. You need final only when accessing a **local variable** from the inner class.

In Java 8, though, even local variables don't need to be declared final. They must simply be *effectively* final, i.e. the compiler is smart enough to check that they're never reassigned.

What is printed is completely normal, as the inner class simply has a reference to the outer class instance, and accesses its field the same way as methods from the outer class would do.

Answer (score 3):

It's defined in the section 8.1.3:

> Inner classes whose declarations do not occur in a static context may freely refer to the instance variables of their enclosing type declaration.

The way it works is straightforward: compiler makes a constructor for your inner class, and passes a reference of the enclosing instance to that constructor. Any time your inner class refers to a variable that has been resolved to a member of the enclosing class, an access is made through the reference stored at the time the object is constructed.

There is no requirement for member variables of enclosed class to be `final`. The requirement applies only to local variables, which are "captured" at the time the object of the inner class is created.